# c++ multi-threading program architecture

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, c++14, c++20

I am currently practicing the use of multiple threads in C++. The program is simplified as follow. In this case, I have a global variable `Obj`, and within each task, a `get` function is processed by thread and thread detach will be called after.

In practice, `get` may take a great amount of time to run. If there are many tasks, get will be called repetitively (since each task has its own get function). I wonder if I can design a program where when one task has already obtained the data using `get` function and the data has been wrote to `obj.text`, then the rest of tasks can directly access or wait for the data from `obj.text`.

Can I use `std::shared_ptr, std::future, std::async` in c++ to implement this? If so, how to design the program? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Info {
public:
  Info() { Ids = 10; };

  int Ids;
  std::string text;
};

Info Objs;

class Module {
public:
  Module() {}
  virtual void check(int &id){};
  virtual void get(){};
};

class task1 : public Module {
public:
  task1() { std::cout << "task1" << std::endl; }
  void check(int &id) override {
    thread s(&task1::get, this);
    s.detach();
  };

  // The function will first do some other work (here, I use sleep to represent
  // that) then set the value of Objs.text
  void get() override {
    // The task may take 2 seconds , So use text instead
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    Objs.text = "AAAA";
    std::cout << Objs.text << std::endl;
  };
};

class task2 : public Module {
public:
  task2() { std::cout << "task2" << std::endl; }
  void check(int &id) override {
    thread s(&task2::get, this);
    s.detach();
  };
  // The function will first do some other work (here, I use sleep to represent
  // that) then set the value of Objs.text
  void get() {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    Objs.text = "AAAA";
    std::cout << Objs.text << std::endl;
  };
};

int main() {
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Module>> modules;

  modules.push_back(std::make_unique<task1>());
  modules.push_back(std::make_unique<task2>());

  for (auto &m : modules) {
    m->check(Objs.Ids);
  }

  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(12));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look up the topic of synchronisation - in particular, techniques to ensure that threads don't simultaneously access an object while another thread is modifying it.    Practically, depending on needs, you might use mutexes (which provide mutual exclusion) or semaphores (which allow limiting the number of threads accessing a shared resource).    The thing to remember is that all of the threads accessing a particular resource need to deliberately cooperate in order to avoid unwanted concurrent access

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: FYI: Most developers expect a member function named `get` to be `const`, they expect it to do little or no work, and they expect it to return a value. Your `get` functions are not `const`, they supposedly "may take a great amount of time to run," and they do _not_ return values. By naming them `get`, you are erecting a mental hurdle that other programmers have to get over in order to understand your code. That makes it less fun for them. It makes it less likely that they will _want_ to read and understand and help you or collaborate with you.

Comment: Your program starts two threads that both store values in the same global variable with no coordination of any kind between them. That's called a "data race," and it usually is pretty much a meaningless thing to do because there's no way to predict which thread will "win" the race and be the last to update the variable. It's great that you have tried to simplify your code example, but I wonder if you have simplified it so much that maybe it no longer illustrates the problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: @Peter: Thanks for narrowing down the question and providing additional knowledge and  a direction for solving the problem.

Comment: @SolomonSlow: Thank you for your valuable feedback and suggestions on the coding style and the question itself. I would say the coding sample here may look confusing as I am still quite new to the system design of c++, but it was not oversimplified. Meanwhile, I am also learning the syntax and usage of modern c++ and am trying to solve the problem accordingly . I will do more research on the topic and improve the code based on your and Peter's suggestions. Thanks again.

Comment: Re, "...not oversimplified..." In that case, you had better find a different way of "returning" results from the two threads. Having both of them store a result into the same global variable usually won't work because of what I said above. Other possibilities include having each thread store its result into a different slot in some global array, or having each thread append its result to the end of a queue or a list.

Answer (score 0):

It is a plain producer-consumer problem.

You have multiple “get()” producers. And did not implemented consumers yet.

First, you should have multiple “Info” for multithread. If there is only one Info, multithread programming is useless. I recommend “concurrent_queue”.

Second, “detach()” is not a good idea. You can’t manage child threads. You’d better use “join()”

My code sample follows. I used Visual Studio 2022

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <concurrent_queue.h>
using namespace std;

class Info {
public:
    Info() { Ids = 10; };
    int Ids;
    std::string text;
};

concurrency::concurrent_queue<Info> Objs;

void producer()
{
    while (true) {
        Info obj;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
        obj.text = "AAAA\n";
        Objs.push(obj);
    }
}

void consumer()
{
    while (true) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        Info obj;
        bool got_it = Objs.try_pop(obj);
        if (got_it) {
            std::cout << obj.text;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    const int NUM_CORES = 6;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CORES / 2; ++i)
        threads.emplace_back(producer);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CORES / 2; ++i)
        threads.emplace_back(consumer);
    for (auto& th : threads) th.join();
}
```